# How to open CSV fle with more than 2GB?

Tags: excel, large-data

I'm trying to open a CSV file with more than 2 GB, but when I open it, all the cells are empty. Is there any way to open it .

I can open it By R , but I want to see the data in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I did something like this in the past. There's a wizard in Execel to import CSV data, you can also transform it in the process.

Hope this helps

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Possibly irrelevant tip - as far as opening big CSV files, I had issues with ll text editors (they just crashed trying to load the big file). Sublime did the trick however.